# Vortex diameter

Tags: fluid-mechanics, aerodynamics, fluid

There exists clear definitions of the size of a vortex core, but vortices affects it surroundings beyond this core. An example is a wing tip vortex which has a small core, but can be seen as a big swirling motion behind an aircraft.

Does someone have a good definition of the diameter of a vortex? Source?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you think that the air in that "swirling motion" will have a centrifugal component?

Comment: the distance they trail the wing is definitely affected among other factors by the weight of the airplane.  Airbus A380 has a  4-7 miles wake. I am alert to leave that space alone in the airports even when they touch down.